# webpack build carpeta javascript

Tags: webpack

Estoy comenzando con webpack:

Mi objetivo es poder tomar una carpeta entera donde tengo todos mis javascript y que se genere  en un build.js minifycado, lo que no encuentro, es como hacer para que el entry de mi webpack.conf sea un folder y no un file, y en el caso de ser un file, como le escribo en dicho file todos los otros archivos que debe incluir.

Hasta ahora estaba haciendo esto con Koala, tomaba un file con los archivos que debía incluir y luego al compilar me quedaba un solo file .js minifycado.

Seguro esto es posible con webpack pero no encuentro la manera de configurarlo

Mi configuración actual es la siguiente:

```
const path = require('path');
const paths = {
  DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/frontend/js'),
  JS: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/frontend/js'),
};




// Webpack configuration
 module.exports = {
    mode: "development", // "production" | "development" | "none"
    entry: paths.JS, // path donde se ejecuta el inicio de la compilacion, path de entrada
      output: {
        path: paths.DIST,
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
      },
};
```

Lo cual me termina tirando un error por el valor de Entry

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Answer (score 0):

No se si es la forma mas correcta, pero encontré una manera de resolverlo:
En mi archivo de cofiguración seteo el entry para app.js

```
entry: path.join(paths.JS, 'app.js'),
```

y en app.js escribo el require de cada file que quiero incluir

```
require('./test1.js');
require('./test2.js');
```

con esto empaqueta todo lo que este seteado dentro del file app.js sin tener que modificar el codigo de todos los archivos js